# Joining table data to features in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, javascript, grass-gis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to make a map using QGIS but I cannot join table data to features in QGIS.

In ArcGIS for Desktop you just open the folder and then join the tabular table with the spatial data table.

Does anyone know how to join table data to features in QGIS?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what version of QGIS you are using, however this functionality is already built in:

e.g. v2.0.1

Non Spatial Join:

- Go to layer Properties>Joins tab and select the plus symbol bottom left cornor to set join parameters

Spatial Join:

- Vector menu>Data Management Tools>Join Attribute by Location